# How to enable backspace on AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Backspace does not work on AutoCompleteTextView, especially once the user has chosen an item from the drop-down list. Is it a recurrent problem ? Did I forget a (well-hidden) permission ?

FYI : programming for Android 2.2

regards

Comment: why do u even need it when user has chosen something by his own wish..:)

Comment: Oh look, almost a year has passed and this bug is not fixed. There must be a workaround!

Comment: wow, you telling me this is not figured out yet?